# how to avoid code from execution which are outside of the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a method, where i am comparing arraylist values inside the for loop. 
I do not want to execute the `Loop 2`(see below code) if any single condition is true for loop1.

Now what happing is, for some values `loop 1` is statisfy and for some other values  `loop 2` satisfy.So beacuse of this i am db is populating with wrong data.

I want to modify my code in such a way that. if any of the array list values are stisfying the `loop 1` then compiler should return from `return ERROR`. It should not execte the code after that.

Loop checking condition is `if(quant>Integer.parseInt(book.getQuantity()))`

Action.java.

```
    public String execute()
{   
      if(id.length == quantity.length)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < id.length; ++i)
       { 
         book = dao.listbookdetailsByBId(id[i]);
         Double dq=new Double(quantity[i]);
         int quant=dq.intValue();  
          if(quant>Integer.parseInt(book.getQuantity()))
          {   
                 //Loop 1  , this is executing if any of the quant is greater then book.getQuantity()..                    
                //i want to stop executing LOOP2 ,if any of the value of quant is greater then book.getQuantity().
              addActionError("You have entered an invalid quantity for the Book Title- ''"+book.getBookTitile()+"''."); 
              return ERROR; 
          }   

    /*  Loop2 starts here
    *   Loop 2 , this is executing if any of the quant is lesser .. 
    *   The below code should execute only if compiler does not reach to the loop1 */

                      // Some DAO code goes here

       }
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply use return (or break)?

Comment: your code seems unclear to me. Where does the first loop end?

Comment: @CodeDreamer  at  `return ERROR;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a break statement

```
if(quant>Integer.parseInt(book.getQuantity()))
      {   
             //Loop 1  , this is executing if any of the quant is greater then book.getQuantity()..                    
            //i want to stop executing LOOP2 ,if any of the value of quant is greater then book.getQuantity().
          addActionError("You have entered an invalid quantity for the Book Title- ''"+book.getBookTitile()+"''."); 
          break; 
      }
```

Comment: yes you are right. i tried it before also. but i was keeping `break;  return ERROR; ` . So i was geting error. Then i finally thought to ask here. Thanks Ali ALamir

Answer (score 0):

You should use a break statement to achieve this, alternatively you can create a local boolean variable and use it to avoid going in loop 2.

```
    if(quant>Integer.parseInt(book.getQuantity()))
          { flag=false;
}

if(flag){
//loop 2
}
```